# R Leaflet Limitations? Too much data?

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial

I found a workaround for this that actually worked better for the project I was working on, but I'm still curious.

I was creating some maps in R using the leaflet package.  The code ran well, but I was using about 1.2 million rows of data and I had 7 layers that I wanted to include in my map.  R studio struggled with, so I saved the map as an HTML file, closed R studio a tried viewing the map in a browser.  It would load after a while, but would always freeze and crash.  My workaround was to create each layer as its own map.  R studio struggled a bit with this, and the HTML files can be a bit sluggish, but everything works.

Does anyone have experience or thoughts on ways to better handle large data sets like this while working with a leaflet?

A second question if you will indulge me- I couldn't figure out how to add a title to the map that wasn't overly distracting from the data I was presenting, which was about the only drawback of splitting the maps up.

Comment: `leaflet` on its own will always struggle with this much data, as it runs purely on the CPU. `leafgl` and `mapdeck` but use underlying WebGL libraries which do all their processing on the GPU and should be able to handle a lot more data.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the `leafgl`-package: https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl
It uses web gl to render leaflet with >1M points blazingly fast compared with the 'default' leaflet-methods...

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, I believe html text is the best way

```
##Set title
library(htmltools)
map_title<-"Your title here"
title_html<-tags$div(
  tags$h3(map_title)
)
```

Then add this to your leaflet definition

`addControl(title_html, position="topleft") # add the title`